# How do you style the HTML5 form validation messages?

Tags: forms, html

Say you have some HTML like this:

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="Some text!" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="An Email!" required>
    <input type="submit" value="A Button!">
</form>
```

Because of the `required` attributes, newer Webkits and Firefoxes show a validation message next to the field if you leave it blank.

They respond to being styled by a rule such as:

```
div {
    font: Helvetica;
}
```

But I can't find a more specific selector for them. Does anyone know what selector is used, or will be used, or even a bug report for webkit/gecko relating to this?

( JSFiddle showing that they can be styled with a div selector: http://jsfiddle.net/p7kK5/ )

Comment: No, but expect it to come through eventually. 

Seems more like a bit of an oversight in the spec - where does the message appear?, where is the message set (without JS)? 

There's an excellent proposal here, http://www.broken-links.com/2011/03/28/html5-form-validation/, but until something like that is added to the spec you'll have to stick to custom validation server-side and client-side

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Chrome does not allow styling form validation bubbles anymore: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259050

Additionally, Firefox has support for the element attribute `x-moz-errormessage` which enables you to change the text of the error message, which is something you could do in Chrome using CSS to and `-webkit-validation-bubble-message`. See more about [`x-moz-errormessage` on the MDN Docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#section_5).

As of yet, Firefox has no way to style the error bubbles.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use more specific selectors for everything else I'm afraid.. body > div etc.

Comment: That was my only thought as well. Not sure I want to go down that route. Guess we'll have to wait for official support.

Comment: @Sheldon what do you mean exactly?