# How to use Email tag in HTML5

Tags: css, html, email-validation

In HTML5 there is a new tag

```
<input type="email">
```

when I am using it in a form, the error it shows when i leave it blank or put a non email text or in it looks pretty weird . How can I change the CSS and text for that error box ??

Comment: What browser/version does it look "weird" in? Also, "email" is not a tag, just an input type.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup

Comment: @amosrivera thanks for link but it says no ways to edit the CSS is it really no ways for that ??

Comment: Nope, niet, nein, niente, nada. If it really matters so much then i suggest you use a js approach

Comment: @amosrivera kkiesss thanksssss

Comment: Posting this as a comment, because I have no experience with it, but according to this article, if the browser supports the CSS3 UI basic module (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/), then there are some pseudo-classes you can use to manipulate the validation. Article here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/forward-thinking-form-validation/ Browser support is limited to newer ones, but a pretty big list.

Comment: @Blake this manipulates the input styling not the popup error..

Comment: @amosrivera my bad, you're correct. I guess i was fooled by the styling around the hints on the sample that they added, which were styled and displaying, not the actual validation messages coming from the browser.

Comment: my bad luck :( ..... any ways thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google Chrome, you could use the following pseudo-classes to style the bubble:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble {}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow-clipper {}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow {}
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {}
```

Not sure if/when other browsers will support styling the error messages.  See the following links for reference:

[Styling HTML5 Form Validation Errors](http://www.broken-links.com/2011/06/16/styling-html5-form-validation-errors/)

[How do you style the HTML5 form validation messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages)