# angular.js validation error message

Tags: angularjs

I have searched and followed the angular code for a long time and cant find where this error message is coming from. I know the validation works but my code only has this:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span></br>
```

but this error comes up:[image]

I cant even find where a concatenation might produce this. The word "Please" is not even in the angular code.

Comment: Guessing here: the browser, because of HTML5 support of "type='email'"?  http://css.dzone.com/news/custom-validation-messages

Comment: Mark, Put it in as an answer so i can give you credit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The browser is generating this message, because of HTML5 support of "type='email'".

Answer (score 10):

you can add 'novalidate' in form to disable native HTML5 validation.

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
```

Comment: this is the proper response

Answer (score 2):

This is due to HTML5. If you don't want to show these messages, add the following to your css:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message { display: none; }
```

However, at the moment this only works for WebKit implementations (Chrome).

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965505/1916258)

Comment: using `novalidate` directive is the angularjs way

Comment: I don't think it's an angular directive. It's part of HTML.