# Customizing Bootstrap's validation tooltip?

Tags: javascript, validation, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Could someone explain to me how to customize Bootstrap's input type="email" validation tooltip like the one below?

[image: tooltip - please enter an email address.]

Or better yet, could someone explain how customize Bootstrap's validation tooltips in general?

---

**EDIT:**

It has been pointed out by [Le_Morri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239349/le-morri) that this is actually a HTML 5 validation tooltip. I am going to leave up the question for other people who make the same mistake as I did.

The following questions will help with HTML5 validation styling,

- [How do you style the HTML5 form validation messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages)
- [How do I style the html 5 form validation error messages with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html-5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css)

Comment: as far as i know they are styled by the browser. [Here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/bring-your-forms-up-to-date-with-css3-and-html5-validation/) you have a guide how do build a workaround.

Comment: @Le_Morri, Oh wow, I had no idea that was an HTML5 thing and had assumed Bootstrap was doing it. Could you make your comment into an answer so I can give you some points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as i know these validation tooltips are not from bootstrap. They are and HTML5 feature and are provided and styled by the browser.

[Here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/bring-your-forms-up-to-date-with-css3-and-html5-validation/) you can find a guide how to create your own validation tooltips.

In Webkit browsers you can style these tooltips a bit using:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

and with the CSS `:invalid` selector you can style the wrong inputs