# HTML5 customize the validation presentation

Tags: html, validation

HTML5 provides an auto popup validation message. [image: See screenshot]

How can I remove this popup and display the message next to the related field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual format of the popup validation message is browser-specific, so you're not going to find a cross-browser, pure-HTML way of changing the way the built-in validation messages are displayed.

If you're willing to use jQuery, consider using something like the [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin, to name just one example.

If you require pure HTML/CSS, your options are quite limited. A few browsers (Webkit-based browsers) will allow the popup boxes to be customized with browser-specific CSS as described in this post: [How do you style the HTML5 form validation messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages)

While it does not control the validation popup, the input itself can be styled using the `:valid` and `:invalid` CSS pseudo-classes. For example:

```
input:valid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
input:invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```