# Apply css on required input field

Tags: css

I want to do styling on the default `required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter Drug Name')"` shown below.

[image: <code>Default</code>]

to something like this.

[image: <code>Sample</code>]

Is it possible to do that? Any help would be nice

**css for the sample picture:**

```
width: 100%;
background: #1A1A1D;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
min-width: 120px;
font-size: 11px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #111;
```

Comment: would you be able to set up a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: okay i try to make one. will take some time

Comment: Irvin Zhan: for the first part. http://jsfiddle.net/e9hbp/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713405/how-do-you-style-the-html5-form-validation-messages/5965505#5965505 which indicates that Chrome no longer allows styling form bubbles any more.