# How to remove standard validation tooltip after .reportValidity() using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

How to remove standard validation tooltip after .reportValidity() using css

[validation tooltip message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef4dZ.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is: "standard". It's not possible to modify (this includes hiding) the actual tooltip because it's a browser native implementation, at least, not possible for major browser engines like Blink, Webkit and Gecko, namely Chromium, Safari and Firefox respectively.

References:

- HTML Specification for `.reportValidity()` behaviour: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#report-validity-steps
- An once-possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965505

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the validation tooltip by setting a custom validation message that is all whitespace. I'm not sure if it is documented somewhere or if it is a bug, but it works in Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tested other browsers.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("name");
input.setCustomValidity(" ");
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => input.reportValidity();
```

```html
<input id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
<button id="btn">Report validity</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form novalidate> ... </form>
```

Comment: A did not use form

Comment: Then do use a form.

Comment: I need logic of reportValidity() but without showing this error tooltip - need validate without showing this tooltip, but thanks of idea

Comment: So, I used focus to trigger custom validation styles. Thanks for help)