# I18n for Rails Javascript Validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I can't find the language file for this text on a Rails form:
[image: form validation]

How can I translate it?

Comment: What gem do you use for the form js-validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because that "tooltip" is not from Rails, is part of the browser implementation of the HTML5 forms. Maybe you are using HTML5 `required` attribute... It uses your browser's language.

Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392882/chrome-popup-please-fill-out-this-field) question.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was using the jquery-ujs validation, but it was the required attribute.