# No attributes available in DOM for Tooltip

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tooltip

I have come across an issue with tooltips...For some tooltips we do not find various attributes like title, etc...
Please help me to identify this tooltip shown in the image below and get this text.

Note: No attribute pertaining to the tooltip is given.Also I have shared the properties for the textbox for "Email"

[image: Tooltip visible,no attributes in DOM]

Any help is appreciated :)..Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You might mention in the body of your question you're trying to script a UI test, I see you have the selenium tag? presumably that's why you need the DOM element?    I'd hazard a guess there is in fact a dom element -  what browser are you using to view the dom here?  in chrome dev tools you should be able to use the element selector to highlight the ui element and see the DOM equivalent.

Comment: I am using firefox..wil try in chrome as well...following your suggestion..

Comment: Observed that the tooltip is not shown in chrome at all.... @TygerKrash

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/135yrvxxaw/how-to-get-tool-tip-text]..the provided link speaks about the native tooltip..and few other things..Is the type of tooltip, the reason that I am unable to identify it

Comment: potentially it's a native chrome tooltip..  this question indicates a tooltip of the same name (and how to disable it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392882/chrome-popup-please-fill-out-this-field

Answer (score 0):

There may be a js function that responds to the mouseover event, or a css rule for :hover attached to the element in some way (likely through the class of the input.)

I would begin my search there.

Comment: Even i believe so.some CSS function has to be there.. I am assuming that when we hover on the textbox,the hidden properties should show up atleast..but even that doesn't seem to be happening..